# ASP.NET MVC not displaying image

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the code below however when i execute the page i get the error as follows

```
/Images/@Model.ImageID.jpeg
```

**Error**

```
CS1061: 'int' does not contain a definition for 'jpeg' and no extension method 'jpeg' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If i do `/Images/@Model.ImageID%20.jpeg`, there is no error but no image is displayed.

Comment: Try - /Images/@(Model.ImageID).jpeg

Comment: Why was this downvoted? @ViktorBahtev That sounds like a great answer, you should post it as such.

Comment: @Viktor Bahtev - Works like a charm. If you post it as answer i'll accept it. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
/Images/@(Model.ImageID).jpeg
```

In your example the Razor View Engine thinks that you want to call property `jpeg` on Model.ImageID but ImageID is of type `int` and does not contain a definition for `jpeg` as the error says. When you add the parenthesis you tell to Razor to execute as expression only what is inside them and `.jpeg` became just a text after the Id. This is called `Explicit expression`.

You can find something useful here - [Razor Syntax Quick Reference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/).